# Android Send Mail: Disable edit in default email composer

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an application. In which i am sending email from my application. I am using the code to send the mail as :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { too });  
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);  

emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);  

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose Email Clients..."));
```

By using this code i am able to send the email. As the default mail composer is accessible.

**My Issue is that :** It is the need of application that user can not edit in the default composer (body, subject and to fields). But the composer fields are editable. So how to make the editable false.

My whole data as body of mail, subject and to whom it is going to send is coming from data base. User is not having authority to change or modify it.

I searched on Google and got some code which send email without using intent, which i feel very complicated. The link is [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

And i got error after following steps given in the link, as :

```
03-07 18:06:05.750: D/dalvikvm(12734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 303K, 53% free 2699K/5639K, external 141K/518K, paused 3ms+2ms
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734): Could not send email
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   nested exception is:
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   java.net.SocketException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.ocs.sendmailcustom.Mail.send(Mail.java:104)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.ocs.sendmailcustom.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:31)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:985)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:945)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
03-07 18:06:26.430: E/MailApp(12734):   ... 19 more
```

I got this error while running the application on device as SAMSUNG galaxy s2.

But it running successfully on LG optimus E400.

So what should i do or follow the step to achieve the task. or is there a way to send mail without intent.

Comment: in the link that you provided you should enter your gmail credentials, and add extra libraries, what is difficult in there

Comment: @Daler Actually i tried to do that but i got error while sending mail by code given in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. As it was a silly mistake on which i forgot to pay attention. As my LG device is worked in GPRS net and my Samsung device is on WI-FI.

So i just include the permission of WI-FI in androidmenifest file as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

After adding this permision i am able to send mail from intent as well as from the code given in [link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) which is custom email sending with out intent.

Hope this post will help in developing e-mail sending app to all.